# Apply CSS to li with group attribute

Tags: html, css

I have to apply CSS for the following list:

```
<div id="divul">
   <ul>
     <li group="opt1">Wake up</li>
     <li>Go to sleep</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How to get the li with from group "opt1" in CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attr-selector

```
li[group=opt1] {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Su7nD/

Answer (score 2):

Use the selector `li[group="opt1"]`, taking advantage of the CSS attribute-equals selector.

References:

- [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use following:

```
#divul ul > li[group="opt1"] {
   /* style you want to apply */
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XK55K/)

Take a look also here:

[custom attributes selectors css](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Su7nD/1/)**

CSS attribute selector `li[group="opt1"]`

css

```
#divul > ul > li[group="opt1"] {
    color: Green;
}
```